# Tab bar, reload every time tab is pressed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I am creating an app in which I have five tabs. I need to reload each controller every time when tab is pressed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put the code you want to reload, in the view will appear or in view did appear of all the view.

All the best.

Comment: thnx for reply.... but i need to make like whenever tab pressed it reload whole page...

Comment: My code already was in viewDidAppear() and it doesn't refresh when the same tab bar button was pressed. The answer seems incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
   // AppDelegate ( and <UITabBarControllerDelegate> )
   // Creation tabbar and controllers               
    UIViewController* myController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    UINavigationController* nav1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myController1] autorelease];

    UIViewController* myController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    UINavigationController* nav2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myController2] autorelease];

    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myController1, myController2, nil];

    UITabBarController* tab = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    tab.viewControllers = array;
    tab.delegate = self; // <-- don't forget set delegate for TabBarController


    // TabBarController Delegate methods   
    - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
    {
            // Reload selected VC's view
        [viewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    //other codes

    [self.tabBarController setDelegate:self]

    //other codes
    }

// UITabBarControllerDelegate method.
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(reloadDataTemp)]) {
        [(YourViewController *)viewController reloadData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So write a method to redraw the elements on your page and call it on tab press.  I will edit this post if you provide more information on the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

if you are you are using the uitableview use this

```
[tableview reloaddata];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are talking about the webview the webview should reload every time a tabbar item is navigated well just implement [webview reload] in the tab bar delegate.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let vc = self.viewControllers?[1] as? stepVC // ViewController That need to be loaded
        vc?.viewDidLoad()

    }
```